# Apply for a German visa on a different passport

Tags: germany

I have quiet an odd question. So I have dual citzenship. I hold an American passport. I also hold a Palestian passport. I have traveled to Germany before visa free on my American passport and I am always granted a 3 month visa upon arrival.

I recently married a German citizen who also hold dual citzenship as a palestianian. We were married in Palestine and all our documentation relating to our marriage including our marriage certificate is from Palestine.

I have a family reunification visa appointment on the 27th with the German embassy in Palestine. I am going to apply for a visa on my Palestinian passport. Do you think they will refuse giving me a visa and tell me to just use my American passport?

The reason I would prefer to use my Palestinian passport for this process is because I want to apply for a residence permit as a Palestinian. I want to be recognized as a Palestian and not an American. I plan on opening a business in Germany and all my information and money comes from Palestine. I am based in Palestine more then the United States. I have not lived there in over 15 years. Should this be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

When you enter into Germany with an American passport, you have an implied visitor's visa. There is no way that this is the equivalent of a family reunification visa and I seriously doubt anybody in a consulate position would get the two confused or suggest an option that is potentially deceitful. As long as you have a valid passport(s), any passport will do. In fact, you technically could get a visa with just the appropriate travel documents. I mention that in particular because there are a number of people living in that region who are considered 'stateless'. The visa you seek is completely independent of the passport used to apply for it.

You won't have any issues with your previous entry into Germany as long as it was liegal and verifiable. That's the main reason they ask.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I know that when I use my American passport I get a visitors visa. I am not confused with that. I want to use my Palestinian passport for my next entry. I have applied for a family reunification visa using my Palestinian passport.  Will the fact that I have a American passport and I have used it to enter Germany before be a conflict. On the visa application it asks if I have entered before and I have answered yes. Will this cause any issues?

Comment: Perhaps, I wasn't clear. It is generally understood among nations that the reason anybody enters a country should align with the status upon which they seek entry. I think it very unlikely anybody in a consulate role would tell you to enter as a visitor (using your American passport) and go through the process of adjusting your status (which I believe you can do in Germany), rather than entering on a visa appropriate for your actual reason for wanting to enter the country. It would be a violation of trust I guess you could say. Is that clearer? I can update the answer.

Comment: You won't have any issues with your previous entry into Germany as long as it was liegal and verifiable. That's the main reason they ask. That's why I said you can use any passport you like. The visa is independent of the passport.

Comment: Ah okay wha your saying makes perfect sense. I know I could actually go ahead and change the status of my stay in Germany on my American passport and apply for a residence visa if I were to get married there on my American passport. But the process is to tideous as it requires me to get documentation from the states which will be difficult to acquire since I don't live there. One of the other things that is required is I need to prove that I have lived there for the past 6 years which I have not that's why I am going through the process on doing it on my Palestinian.

Comment: I was also told that since I  am of American nationality also it makes the process a lot easier when I share that information with embassy when I apply. Someone told me it's basically a gurantee visa since I hold American nationality also.

Comment: Yes, I've heard that that adjustment route is considerably more bureaucratic. Out of curiousity, do you still have to meet the language requirements with the family reunification route? As far as it being easier for an American, technically all are treated the same. In reality, it's almost certainly an open/shut case for Americans. Not fair perhaps, but just reality.

Comment: Now I believe that I do have to meet the Language requirements. People coming from Palestine on family reunification do need to attend an A-1 level class. I attended the class and got my certificate of attendence. I took it a while back. Now I would believe technically it would be required of me. But in reality they might look over it as for the nationality issue and that I have visted twice before. Which were both stays for over a month. I included this information on my visa application.

Comment: Be prepared for them to ask you a question or two in German. Nothing complicated, but to just see if you can even pick up a simple bit of syntax. I faced this when applying for a work visa (fortunately I'm more-or-less fluent). I've updated the question.

Comment: I think I can handle their questions. I'll brush up a bit. My comprehension is fine. Hopefully it won't be an issue! Thanks for all the information!